# Using $crate in Rust's procedural macros?

Tags: macros, rust

I know what the [`$crate`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.5.0/book/macros.html#the-variable-crate) variable is, but as far as I can tell, it can't be used inside procedural macros. Is there another way to achieve a similar effect?

I have an example that roughly requires me to write something like this using [quote](https://github.com/dtolnay/quote) and nightly Rust

```
quote!(
     struct Foo {
        bar: [SomeTrait;#len]
     }
)
```

I need to make sure `SomeTrait` is in scope (`#len` is referencing an integer outside the scope of the snippet).

I am using procedural macros 2.0 on nightly using quote and syn because `proc-macro-hack` didn't work for me. [This is the example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=c3739bef9d9d64400d9653b245582892&version=nightly) I'm trying to generalize.

Comment: 1. Is your procedural macro really generating a struct and not an impl block? For dumb reasons, the most reliable approach is way more complicated for macros that generate a struct compared to macros that generate an impl.

Comment: 2. Is this for a proc_macro_derive macro, or a different type of procedural macro?

Comment: 3. `[SomeTrait; #len]` is not a thing you can do, because `[T; n]` requires `T: Sized`. See https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=bb33e5ba42a7e64af998b014483329f0. Can you clarify the intended result?

Comment: @dtolnay: 1. It's generating a struct and an impl block. 2. This is for Nightly Macros 2.0 ; 3. Something like https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=415163c29391484ada4c876553ebf23f&version=stable&backtrace=0 (I need procedural macros, since I want to parse first parameter in specific way)

Comment: @dtolnay Updated questions with clarification.

Comment: [Issue on the Rust repository on this topic](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/54363)

Answer (score 10):

Since Rust 1.34, you can use `extern crate self as my_crate`, and use `my_crate::Foo` instead of `$crate::Foo`.

https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/54647

https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/57407

(Credit: Neptunepink ##rust irc.freenode.net)

Answer (score 4):

Based on replies from https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/38356#issuecomment-412920528, it looks like there is no way to do this (as of 2018-08), neither to refer to the proc-macro crate nor to refer to any other crate unambiguously.

Answer (score 2):

In Edition 2015 (classic Rust), you can do this (but it's hacky):

- use `::defining_crate::SomeTrait` in the macro
- within third-party crates depending on `defining_crate`, the above works fine
- within `defining_crate` itself, add a module in the root:

  `mod defining_crate { pub use super::*; }`

In Edition 2018 even more hacky solutions are required (see [this issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/54647)), though [#55275](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/55275) may give us a simple workaround.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your proc-macro inside a declarative macro, and pass the `$crate` identifier to your proc-macro for reuse (see [this commit](https://github.com/x-hgg-x/custom-format/blob/bdc31a66d7940c3c4ed5680271f86fca1c70cde9/src/lib.rs#L44) for example). It will create a [proc_macro::Ident](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/proc_macro/struct.Ident.html) value with the special `$crate` identifier.

Note that you cannot manually create such an identifier, since `$` is normally invalid inside identifiers.

Comment: This won't work for attribute macros I believe

Answer (score -1):

Since Rust 1.45, you can use [`Span::mixed_site`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/proc_macro/struct.Span.html#method.mixed_site) as an [`Ident`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/proc_macro/struct.Ident.html)s span to use `$crate` directly and avoid conflicts with local variables.

```rust
quote_spanned!(Span::mixed_site()=>
     struct Foo {
        bar: [$crate::SomeTrait; #len]
     }
)
```

Comment: Hey, I tried this approach but it doesn't work for me. See [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76228239/14385360).