# How do I write a procedural macro that expands to a macro invocation without requiring users to import the crate for the macro?

Tags: rust, macros, rust-proc-macros

I'm trying to write a function-like procedural macro `my_macro` that expands to a `lazy_static` macro invocation. I want to write it in a way that users of `my_macro` don't need to list `lazy_static` in their crate's dependencies and explicitly use it (`use lazy_static::lazy_static`).

This is the minimal example code:

**lib.rs (my_macro crate)**

```
extern crate proc_macro;
use proc_macro::TokenStream;
use quote::quote;

#[proc_macro]
pub fn my_macro(_item: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    quote!(
        lazy_static! {
            static ref EXAMPLE: u8 = 42;
        }
    ).into()
}
```

**Cargo.toml (my_macro crate)**

```
[package]
name = "my_macro"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
quote = "0.6"
lazy_static = "1.2.0"

[lib]
proc-macro = true
```

**lib.rs (usage crate)**

```
use my_macro::my_macro;
// use lazy_static::lazy_static;

my_macro!();

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    #[test]
    fn it_works() {
        assert_eq!(*EXAMPLE, 42);
    }
}
```

**Cargo.toml (usage crate)**

```
[package]
name = "import_test"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
my_macro = { path = "./my_macro" }
# lazy_static = "1.2.0"
```

The code above results in a compile error:

```
error: cannot find macro `lazy_static!` in this scope
 --> src/lib.rs:6:1
  |
6 | my_macro!();
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I understand the error and I know that I can solve it by letting the `usage` crate depend on `lazy_static` and `use` it in `lib.rs` (see commented lines).

The problem is that this would mean that all crates that use `my_macro` would have to list `lazy_static` in their dependencies. This doesn't seem right and I'd like to know if there's an alternative. I already tried a couple of things but nothing solved the problem.

Comment: I don't think there is a good solution to that problem yet. [Related Rust issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/54363) and [somewhat related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44950574/using-crate-in-rusts-procedural-macros).